# Interrupting animated navigation on Android results in blank screen

Tags: android, animation, navigation, transition, androidx

I have trouble with animations between fragments. When quickly pressing the back button during a fragment transition, I can achieve a state where the `NavHostFragment` inside an activity layout appears empty.

Here is a video that demonstrates the issue:

[image]

As you can see in the video, pressing the back button *after* the transition is finished pops the second fragment, as expected. However when the animation is still *in progress*, sometimes pressing the back button clears the whole `NavHostFragment` and I am presented with an empty view.

The longer the animation is, the more likely I am to get the blank screen. Maybe I'm not applying the animation correctly, so below is all the relevant code for this example.

`MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_test);
    }
}
```

`FirstFragment`:

```
public class FirstFragment extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view.findViewById(R.id.to_second_fragment).setOnClickListener(v -> androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_first_fragment_to_second_fragment));
    }
}
```

`activity_navigation_test`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_test" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`navigation_test`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_test"
    app:startDestination="@id/first_fragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/first_fragment"
        android:name="com.test.navigation.FirstFragment"
        android:label="fragment_first"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_first_fragment_to_second_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/second_fragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_from_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_a_little_out_to_left" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/second_fragment"
        android:name="com.test.navigation.SecondFragment"
        android:label="fragment_second"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second" />
</navigation>
```

`slide_in_from_right` (`slide_a_little_out_to_left` is the same except for fromX and toX values):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="666"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">

    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%"
               android:toXDelta="0"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" />
</set>
```

I am using the following library versions:

```
androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha02
androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5
androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.1
androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.1
```

Comment: `appcompat:1.3.0-alpha02` depends on an older version of Fragments (1.3.0-alpha08) that is overriding your `fragment:1.2.5` dependency. Do you see the same issue when you upgrade to the latest Fragment 1.3.0-beta02?

Comment: I was actuall using version 1.3.0-beta01 in the real project but the issue was all the same. Anyway, the update to 1.3.0-beta02 did the trick, thank you very much! The [change notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0-beta02) do mention this; glad this got fixed, we're releasing soon. You can post this as an answer here, if you want the rep :)